# Sequence of polynomials that converges to $|x|$ over $[-1,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

Suppose I want to construct a sequence of polynomials that converges to $|x|$ pointwise.

I am pretty good on proving that sequences of functions converge to things pointwise, but I am having trouble actually coming up with a sequence of polynomials that converges to $|x|$. Someone told me to try using the Taylor series expansion of $(1−x)^{1/2}$, but that just confused me, since I am very rusty on Taylor series. Would anyone mind explaining this to me a little?

Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe with an [orthogonal polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_orthogonal_polynomials)?

Comment: Over what domain?

Comment: The Bernstein polynomials are a nice way of approximating a continuous function over $[0,1]$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial

Answer (score 3):

You can use Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind.

$$ P_{2n}(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}-\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{4(-1)^j}{\pi(4j^2-1)}T_{2j}(x)$$

converges uniformly to $|x|$ over the compact set $[-1,1]$, in virtue of the Fourier-Chebyshev series (the Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind are a complete base of orthonormal functions wrt the scalar product $<f,g>=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{f(x)g(x)dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$).

This choice is quite good since:

$$ \sup_{x\in(-1,1)}||x|-P_{2n}(x)|=O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).$$

See also: Weierstrass approximation Theorem.